# Shall I use 'pursue my passion for' or 'in'?

Tags: prepositions

I want to say something like

> Being interested in politics, I have pursued my passion **for**/**in** it by....

Under this context shall I use **for** or **in**?

Comment: Passion for. 100% without question.

Comment: @JMB Any explanation? Since *in* was used (in politics), why change to *for*? Are you saying it is a set phrase?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Passion in X* would mean you are passionate about something within X.  When you say this without further information, someone might follow up with the question, "What are you passionate about in politics?", for example.

If you are passionate about the entirety of X, then use *for*.